# Passing JSON object to ng-init

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i'm trying to pass a JSON Object to my app using ng-init + stringify but it doesn't work i get a Lexer error.

`Lexer Error: Unexpected nextharacter  at columns 8-8 [#] in expression [friends=#{JSON.stringify(friends)}].`

**Javascript**

```
var friends = [
{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
{name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
{name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
{name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
{name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
{name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}
];

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="friends=#{JSON.stringify(friends)}"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try with those quotes:

```
<div ng-init="friends='#{JSON.stringify(friends)}'"></div>
```

I don't know what's your templating engine, but with ejs for example it would be:

```
<div ng-init="friends='<%= JSON.stringify(friends) %>'"></div>
```

Also if you have some issue with some simple or/and doubles quotes you can do replace them with a regexp like that:

```
<div ng-init="friends='<%= JSON.stringify(friends).replace(/"/g, "\\\"").replace(/'/g, "\\'") %>'">
```

**I don't know if it's a best practice or not in angular**, but thanks to this I could share some data previously retrieved from server to angular. This way I prevented many requests from Angulars controllers to the public API which requested the backend.

And in the angular side, you can do something like that: `$scope.friends = JSON.parse(friends)` to "expose" your json.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in the angular way, you can access the javascript variable using `$window` of angularjs and convert it to `$scope` variable in the controller and can access it in the html

Take a look into your code, i just modified it a little to make it work,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<script>
  var friends = [
    {name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
    {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}
  ];

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.friendsInscope = $window.friends;
}]);

</script>
<!--<div ng-init="friends=#{JSON.stringify(friends)}">{{friends}}</div>-->
<div ng-init="friends=friendsInscope">{{friends|| json}}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HC2QXmQO1EyNOJkPnPX?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Angular is working with scopes, it has no access to global variables/functions. So it will never use your `friends` variable, neither it is possible to access `JSON.stringify` from expression. Also there is no `#{}` operator in Angular, about which it told you in the error description.

I would suggest you to read:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression